# How i make a robot arm?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to build a robotic application where an arm can press a switch and rotate a knob.
Which robotic arm I need to pick for this?
it is better if it is controled by arduino.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214410/how-i-make-a-robot-arm?/) by [AdamJonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/23317/adamjonny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2015-07-23**:
Hello. You might have more input from a site that focuses more on hardware if you're planning to build your own. One of my favorites is [letsmakerobot.com](http://letsmakerobots.com/). There are plenty of helpful people there, and many example builds with open designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 Hi,friend.
 I  found a similar project:A Robot Arm base on Arduino with high precision 0.3mm and Opensource call dobot.This product will be soon on kickstarter one or two weeks later, please looking forward to it.   (https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/561930872/956638568?token=5b65efe7)
```

[image: image description]

you can learn about it on:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vK4cYl-o3K0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrmOFbSAW2Y

---

Originally posted by [JerryLiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/23000/jerryliu/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-07-23**:
Looks nice! Do have more information?

**Comment by [AdamJonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/23317/adamjonny/) on 2015-07-23**:
thanks!
is it there some way to buy the components?